# android array adapter changing data

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```html
Here is my main class and Adapter together
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public  MyAdapter adapter;
private View view;
Context context;
public  ListView list;

public int t[];

public SharedPreferences prefs;
public SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
public SharedPreferences preferences;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

int [] btnNums={66,150,94,72,206,489,1481,731,131,91,145,137,662,770};
int [] tuesdaynum={351,14,308,19,134,514,305,68,104,129,62,47,409,630};
int [] wednesdaynum={744,131,184,846,37,336,812,88,1020,1286,1106,551,202,156};
int [] thursdaynum={206,662,731,1281,801,351,117,770,302,526,212,1100,1060,1100};
int [] fridaynum={232,998,209,80,73,270,312,55,110,78,209,114,161,1001};

int [] saturdaynum={20,48,573,319,108,66,116,500,46,68,286,201,256,113};
int [] sundaynum={137,148,56,124,68,490,18,156,14,48,20,86,514,298};

int [] btnNumsrefs={66,150,94,72,206,489,1481,731,131,91,145,137,662,770};

int yesterday;


public void storeYesterday(Calendar a){
    yesterday=a.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    preferences=getSharedPreferences("yesterday",0);
    editor=preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("yesterday",yesterday);

    editor.commit();
    
}


public Integer getFromYesterday(){
    preferences=getSharedPreferences("yesterday",0);
        int get =preferences.getInt("yesterday", 0);

    return get;
}



int[] images = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6, R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8, R.drawable.a9,
        R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12, R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14};


int[] tuesday = {R.drawable.elkahhar, R.drawable.elvehhab, R.drawable.errezzak, R.drawable.elvahid, R.drawable.essamed, R.drawable.elkabid, R.drawable.elkadir, R.drawable.elhakem, R.drawable.eladl,
        R.drawable.ellatif, R.drawable.elbatin, R.drawable.elvali, R.drawable.ettevvab, R.drawable.elmuntekim};
int[] wednesday = {R.drawable.elmuktedir, R.drawable.esselam, R.drawable.elmukaddim, R.drawable.elmuaahir, R.drawable.elevvel, R.drawable.elmusavvir, R.drawable.elhabir, R.drawable.elhalim, R.drawable.elazim,
        R.drawable.elgafur, R.drawable.ezzahir, R.drawable.elmuteali, R.drawable.elberr, R.drawable.elafuv };



int[] thursday = {R.drawable.elcebbar, R.drawable.elmutekebbir2, R.drawable.elhaliik, R.drawable.elgafffar, R.drawable.ellahir, R.drawable.errafi, R.drawable.elmuiz, R.drawable.elmuzil, R.drawable.elbasir,
        R.drawable.essekur, R.drawable.malikulmulk, R.drawable.zulcelalilikram, R.drawable.elganiy, R.drawable.elmugni };



int[] friday = {R.drawable.elkebir, R.drawable.elhafiz, R.drawable.elmukit, R.drawable.elhasib, R.drawable.elcelil, R.drawable.elkerim, R.drawable.elrakib, R.drawable.elmucib, R.drawable.elaliy,
        R.drawable.elhakim, R.drawable.elmuksit, R.drawable.elcami, R.drawable.elmani, R.drawable.eddar};

int[] saturday = {R.drawable.elvedud, R.drawable.elmecid, R.drawable.elbais, R.drawable.essehid, R.drawable.elhak, R.drawable.elvekil, R.drawable.elkaviy, R.drawable.elmetin, R.drawable.elveliy,
        R.drawable.elhamid, R.drawable.errauf, R.drawable.ennafi, R.drawable.ennur, R.drawable.elbaki};
int[] sunday = {R.drawable.elvasi, R.drawable.elmuhsi, R.drawable.elmubdi, R.drawable.elmuid, R.drawable.elmuhyi, R.drawable.elmumit, R.drawable.elhay, R.drawable.elkayyum, R.drawable.elvacid,
        R.drawable.elmacid, R.drawable.elhadi, R.drawable.elbedi, R.drawable.erresid, R.drawable.essabur };
String[] exp;
String[] exp2;
String[] exp3;
String[] exp4;
String[] exp5;
String[] exp6;
String[] exp7;

String[] mean;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit= this.getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_APPEND).edit();
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_APPEND);

    view=getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    Admob.createLoadBanner(getApplicationContext(), view);
    Admob.createLoadInterstitial(getApplicationContext(), null);




    Resources  res=getResources();




    exp= res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
    exp2= res.getStringArray(R.array.faz2);
    exp3= res.getStringArray(R.array.faz3);
    exp4= res.getStringArray(R.array.faz4);
    exp5= res.getStringArray(R.array.faz5);
    exp6= res.getStringArray(R.array.faz6);
    exp7= res.getStringArray(R.array.faz7);
    mean=res.getStringArray(R.array.anlam);
    list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(new Date());




    int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    if(today==Calendar.Monday){
      adapter.setData(this,exp3,thursday,mean,thursdaynum);

    }else if(today==Calendar.TUESDAY){
        adapter.clear();
        adapter=new MyAdapter(this,exp2,tuesday,mean,tuesdaynum);

    }//goes on
        if(getFromYesterday()==null){
            storeYesterday(cal);

        }else  {
            if(today!=getFromYesterday()) {


                storeYesterday(cal);

                adapter = new MyAdapter(this, exp, images, mean, t);
                storeYesterday(cal);

                edit.putInt("Count", btnNumsrefs.length);
                int count = 0;
                for (int i : btnNums) {
                    edit.putInt("IntValue_" + count++, i);
                }
            }
                edit.commit();
        }



    int[] ret;
    Integer  count1 = prefs.getInt("Count", 0);
    if(count1!=null) {
        ret = new int[count1];
        for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
            ret[i] = prefs.getInt("IntValue_" + i, i);
            t=ret;
        }
    }



    if(t!=null)
    {




            adapter = new MyAdapter(this, exp, images, mean, t);

    }else

    {
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, exp, images, mean, btnNums);

    }
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    context=getApplicationContext();
}

}

class  MyAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    int [] images;
    String [] titleArray;
    String [] descriptionArray;
    int [] btnNums;
    MainActivity ma;








    public MyAdapter(MainActivity m, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] descp, int[] btnNum ){

        super(m, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView,titles);
        this.images=imgs;
        this.titleArray=titles;
        this.descriptionArray=descp;
        btnNums=btnNum;


        this.ma=m;







    }
  
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) ma.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        final TextView myTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        myTitle.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        final TextView descp=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Button button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.angry_btn);
        final Vibrator a = (Vibrator) ma.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);








        if(ma.t!=null)
        {


            for(int i=0; i<14;i++){
                if (btnNums[position] <= 0) {

                    button.setText("OK");







                 /*   Integer index=(Integer) convertView.getTag();
                  ma.list.removeViewAt(index);
                    ma.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    */

                }else {
                    button.setText("" + ma.t[position]);


                }
                //   button.setText("" + ma.t[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                descp.setText(descriptionArray[position]);


            }
        }else
        {

            for(int i=0; i<14;i++){

                if (btnNums[position] <= 0) {

                    button.setText("OK");

                 /*   Integer index=(Integer) convertView.getTag();
                  ma.list.removeViewAt(index);
                    ma.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    */

                }else {
                    button.setText("" + btnNums[position]);


                }
                // button.setText("" + btnNums[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                descp.setText(descriptionArray[position]);


            }
        }



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                btnNums[position]--;

                storeIntArray(btnNums);


                a.vibrate(30);





                int temp[]=getFromPrefs();
                ma.t=temp;

                for (int i = 0; i <14; i++) {
                    if (btnNums[position] <= 0) {

                        button.setText("OK");

                 /*   Integer index=(Integer) convertView.getTag();
                  ma.list.removeViewAt(index);
                    ma.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    */

                    }else {
                        button.setText("" + temp[position]);


                    }

                    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                    descp.setText(descriptionArray[position]);


                }
            }
        });




        return row;



    }
```

In my app,  I use custom list view with different datas. these datas come from arrays , I want to send new arrays via constructor to my adapter by checking date but it doesn't work .

after these codes I used these lines

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please help I am stucked.

Comment: post the code of MyAdapter, I need to confirm its correct before making any suggestion

Comment: I posted the code of MyAdapter. I am using this adapter in Activity class.

Comment: there is no solution ?

Comment: There is always a solution. Well your adapter class looks fine so far, I wanted to confirm you were passing your array to the adapter super(). Now I would need need to see the code for the activity

Comment: I updated the code, thanks a lot  for giving your attention to my problem.

Comment: in your activity code, before you call `if(true){
      adapter.setData(this,exp3,thursday,mean,thursdaynum);` adapter has not been initialized. Initialize it i.e adapter=new MyAdapter(...)

Comment: I actually tried it but had problems with parameters Can you help at this point please ?

Comment: Hope you did not put (...) like I wrote? by **...** I meant initialize the adapter like this: `adapter=new MyAdapter(this,exp3,thursday,mean,thursdaynum);`  I dont think my parameters are correct but its your code, you should know the correct parameters to initialize with

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a setData() method in your adapter where you're clearing the current data and setting the new one and then call the notifyDataSetChanged method.

This way you will not create and set the same adapter multiple times when you want to change the data.

Comment: public void setData(String[] title,int imgs[],String[] desp, int [] btnNum){
        clear();
        titleArray=title;
        images=imgs;
        descriptionArray=desp;
        btnNums=btnNum;
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

Comment: I used this code but I got         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.arksoft.maneviyatvakti.MyAdapter.setData(java.lang.String[], int[], java.lang.String[], int[])' on a null object reference

Comment: First you have to instantiate your adapter before setting it to the list and then call the setData method.